# forbidden : no permission to access /***.php on localhost error

Tags: php, android, apache, http-error

I am trying to read the response from a page on localhost.

 I have the following code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myIpAddress/mySite/myFile.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("send_xml", "true"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            InputStream is=response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.e(tag, "response: "+sb.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(tag, "error: "+e.toString());
        }
```

I am getting the following response in logcat:

```
09-09 20:56:19.151: ERROR/ca(507): response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
09-09 20:56:19.151: ERROR/ca(507): <html><head>
09-09 20:56:19.151: ERROR/ca(507): <title>403 Forbidden</title>
09-09 20:56:19.151: ERROR/ca(507): </head><body>
09-09 20:56:19.151: ERROR/ca(507): <h1>Forbidden</h1>
09-09 20:56:19.151: ERROR/ca(507): <p>You don't have permission to access /mySite/myFile.php
09-09 20:56:19.151: ERROR/ca(507): on this server.</p>
09-09 20:56:19.151: ERROR/ca(507): </body></html>
```

I have wamp, with PHP 5.3.5, Apache 2.2.17, MySQL 5.5.8.

 Why am I not able to access files on localhost? 

 What is the solution?

 I have a file called index.html in the folder mySite. 

 Thank you.

**EDIT:** If I use localhost/mySite/myFile.php I am able to access it, but if I use localhost/mySite/myFile.php I am not able to access it.

 But I cannot use localhost because I am using an emulator and localhost/127.0.0.1 returns the emulated phone.

 Hope this helps.

Comment: what are the permissions for /mySite/myFile.php?

Comment: Are you able to hit that url using a normal browser? a 403 error usually means that apache itself does not have permission to read that directory/file.

Comment: @Marc B yes I checked that. I can access the file using chrome. thetaiko I dont know. I guess I can access it from my computer if thats what you are asking for.

Comment: @Marc B please check my edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some looking around fixed it. The problem was solved by solution 'e' [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-403-forbidden-error-and-solution/).

 Problem was with the apache server being constrained initially.

Comment: hello, can you explain how to do the solution "e"? I'm not a server guy, so I don't this kind of thing..thank you..

Answer (score 0):

well it is very easy. for example if you want a acces test.php file at your android device via chrome or standart internet explorer.

first of all save your php file in

> c:/wamp/www/testfolder

second open

> wamp/alias

directory and create a config file (for me, testfolder.conf)and write in thoses codes:

```
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/testfolder/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    Allow from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and save and close. restart wampserver and finished!